# метод для проверки объекта класса на валидность с помощью рефлексии

Tags: java

Подскажите плз правильно ли я понял задачу и правильно ли сделал её суть задачи:
Создать метод для проверки объекта класса User на валидность.

User должен содержать приватные поля:

```
String surname;
String name;
int age;
String email;
String phone;
```

Добавьте конструктор по умолчанию и с параметрами.

Создать исключение UserValidException, которое будет содержать информацию
о том какое поле не проинициализировано, либо о поле, которое содержит неправильное значение.

Метод должен с помощью рефлексии проверять все поля.
Метод должен выкидывать UserValidException исключение с информацией о поле, которое не соответствует требованиям.

### Требования к юзеру:

1. -поля не должны быть равны null
2. -имя или фамилия не должны содержать числа или специальные символы
3. -почта должна содержать 1 или более символов до @, 1 или более символов от собачки до точки, и не меньше двух символов после точки,
   почта не должна содержать специальных символов, кроме: _ @ .
4. -номер должен содержать только цифры, начинаться с ноля и должен содержать 10 цифр: 0991112233

### Main:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Home_Work_Exceptions_Reflection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setSurname("Sidorenko");
        user.setName("Valerii");
        user.setAge(36);
        user.setEmail("Sidorenko.Valerii@gmail.com");
        user.setPhone("0982094801");
        System.out.println(user);
        Class<User> userClass = User.class;
        Field[] declaredFields = userClass.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field declaredField : declaredFields) {
            System.out.println(declaredField);
        }
    }

}
```

### Class User:

```
public class User {

    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String surname, String name, int age, String email, String phone) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        if (surname == null || !surname.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
            try {
                throw new UserValidException();
            } catch (UserValidException ex) {
                System.out.println("Поле Surname не должно быть пустым или содержать числа или специальные символы");
            }
        }
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (name == null || !name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
            try {
                throw new UserValidException();
            } catch (UserValidException ex) {
                System.out.println("Поле Name не должно быть пустым или содержать числа или специальные символы");
            }
        }
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        if (age == 0 || age <= 0 || age >= 100) {
            try {
                throw new UserValidException();
            } catch (UserValidException ex) {
                System.out.println("Укажите правильно поле Age");
            }
        }
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        if (email == null || !email.matches("^((\\w|[-+])+(\\.[\\w-]+)*@[\\w-]+((\\.[\\d\\p{Alpha}]+)*(\\.\\p{Alpha}{2,})*)*)$")) {
            try {
                throw new UserValidException();
            } catch (UserValidException ex) {
                System.out.println("Email должна содержать 1 или более символов до @, 1 или более символов от собачки до точки,\n"
                        + " и не меньше двух символов после точки, почта не должна содержать специальных символов, кроме: _ @ .");
            }
        }
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        if (phone == null || !phone.matches("^([0]){1}([0-9]){9}$")) {
            try {
                throw new UserValidException();
            } catch (UserValidException ex) {
                System.out.println("Поле Phone должен содержать только цифры, начинаться с ноля и должен содержать 10 цифр: 0991112233");
            }
        }
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User { " + "Surname: " + surname + ", Name: " + name + ", Age: " + age + ", Email: " + email + ", Phone: " + phone + '}';
    }

}
```

### Class UserValidException :

```
public class UserValidException extends Exception {

    public UserValidException() {
    }

    public UserValidException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public UserValidException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public UserValidException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public UserValidException(String message, Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace) {
        super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
    }

}
```

Самое не понятное для меня это как сделать метод который  должен с помощью рефлексии проверять все поля. И сделал ли я все верно ?

Comment: не совсем, вы делаете все проверки в сеттерах, тем самым обеспечивая валидность юзеров. Вам же, по всей видимости, требуется делать эти проверки внутри какого-то метода(не обязательно члена класа User), где вы будете получать значения полей с помощью рефлексии

Comment: вот я и не могу понять что нужно сделать )

Answer (score 0):

Имелось в виду проверку сделать не в геттерах и сетерах. А методом внутри мейна при помощи рефлексии что-то типо того:

```
  private static void validate(User user) throws IllegalAccessException, UserValidException {
    for (Field field : User.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if(field.get(user) == null) throw new UserValidException();
    }
    if(user.getPhone().charAt(0) != '0') throw new UserValidException();
    //Остальные проверки
  }
```

Думаю суть ясна. Ну и думаю в модели лучше int превратить в Integer

Answer (score 0):

**В дополнение к ответу *Gwaeren*.**

Метод `valivate()` стоит записать так:

```java
static void validate(User user) throws IllegalAccessException, UserValidException, NoSuchFieldException {
    String surname = (String)User.class.getDeclaredField("surname").get(user);
    if(surname == null || !surname.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) throw new UserValidException();
    // и так далее для всех полей
}
```

Comment: В вашем способе поле surname ненаходит

Comment: @EvgeniyRadion теперь должно работать.

Comment: к сожалению не то =( я его теперь вызвать не могу(

Comment: @EvgeniyRadion почему вы не можете его вызвать?

Comment: Ошибка: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: @EvgeniyRadion теперь будет работать.

Comment: неа=)))), слуш, а можно с тобой как то связатся ?) мне нужна помощь мб подскажешь

Comment: У меня работает. Можно, я сейчас перемещу разговор в чат, а из него уже можно в личные сообщения перейти.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96433/discussion-between---and-evgeniy-radion).

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйся Hibernate Validator и Jakarta
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html/development_guide/jakarta_bean_validation

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)